# The study of Hausdorff distance as a pseudometric.

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces

In hyperspace theory, if $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then the Hausdorff distance between nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ can be defined as $$H(A,B)=\text{max}\{\text{sup}\{d(a,B): a\in A\},\text{sup}\{d(b,A): b\in B\} \}$$ [This is](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~brweber/Lectures/USTC2011/Lecture%205%20-%20Gromov-Hausdorff%20distance.pdf) "the farthest distance any point of $B$ is from the set $A$, or the farthest
any point of $A$ is from $B$, whichever is greater." In general, $H$ is not a metric, but a pseudometric (for $H(A,B)=0$ if and only if $\overline{A}=\overline{B}$, where overline denotes closure.)

Every article I've read about the Hausdorff distance only studies it in the hyperspace of closed sets, because it is a metric there, however I am interested in its properties as a (possibly extended) pseudometric in the power set of $X$ minus the empty set. I find the property I mentioned above incredibly useful and interesting, so I was wondering if there are any texts that address this topic any further. Pseudometric spaces seem more exotic and attractive to me lately.

Does anyone know more about Hausdorff distance as a pseudometric?

Comment: "Pseudometric spaces seem more exotic and attractive to me lately." I'm not sure why. If you quotient out by the equivalence relation $x \sim y \iff \rho(x, y) = 0$, then you're back to a metric space. In the case of the Hasudorff pseudometric, $A \sim B \iff \overline{A} = \overline{B}$, so $H(A, B) = H(\overline{A}, \overline{B})$ for all non-empty $A, B \subseteq X$. Considering non-closed sets adds no real interesting structure. (Personally, I'm more interested in non-symmetric metrics these days, such as $\sup_{a \in A} d(a, B)$!)

Comment: Yes, however if for some reason the equivalence classes of $\sim$ turn out to be open sets, then the pseudometric space is Alexandroff quasi-discrete, and the quotient becomes discrete - not too interesting :(. 

The reason why I am interested in pseudometric spaces is precisely because the particular one I'm studying is totally bounded Alexandroff quasi-discrete. I believe the Hausdorff distance will provide a lot of insight into this space, but I need it as a pseudometric, not a metric.

Comment: As best I can tell, the equivalence classes of $H$ are open if and only if the quotient metric space is discrete, if and only if $X$ is discrete.